# How to create non-hierarchical relationship circular diagram with D3.js?

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization

I'm trying to create a diagram which shows links between nodes on the same hierarchy level but witthin different groups in a circular layout. It's basically a visualisation of keywords/tags/groups attached to objects a la [Circos](http://circos.ca/images/samples/):

```
var data = 
    [
        {
            "name": "Adam",
            "tags": ["tall", "blonde"]
        },
        {
            "name": "Barbara",
            "tags": ["tall", "brunette", "student", "single"]
        }
    ];
```

Or, like something I'm trying to do:

```
var data =
    [
        {
            "name": "Project 1",
            "categories":
            [
                "Category A",
                "Category B",
                "Category C",
                "Category D"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Project 2",
            "categories":
            [
                "Category C",
                "Category D",
                "Category E"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Project 3",
            "categories":
            [
                "Category A",
                "Category E"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Project 4",
            "categories":
            [
                "Category A",
                "Category C",
                "Category D",
                "Category E"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Project 5",
            "categories":
            [
                "Category A",
                "Category B",
                "Category D"
            ]
        }
    ];
```

Each object can have a number of categories corresponding to the number of node copies appearing in the circle. Visually, it should look something like this:

[image: Circular Diagram]

Is it possible with D3.js? If so, which layout? It looks like it would be something between [chord](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Chord-Layout) (but without values) and [bundle](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Bundle-Layout) (without hierarchy).

I'd imagine the script would need to traverse through the JSON data and find all unique categories first and then distribute and interlink nodes of each object depending on what and how many categories are attached to it. Finally, it would label each category.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: This example is inspired by Circos http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062006

Comment: Any solutions ?